# Why I can't addUsersObject:(User *)value

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, tableview

I have 2 entities: Event and User.

Event has many users. I have a tableview that lists all the events and when i click on one row, i get this row's managed object. and i set the destination view controler's managed object to this. Everything is working, but i can't `addUsersObject`. There is no code hint.
the code like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Event *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    EventsViewController *eventsVC = [[EventsViewController alloc] init];
    eventsVC.event = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventsVC animated:YES];
}
```

Event.h

```
@interface Event (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addUsersObject:(User *)value;
- (void)removeUsersObject:(User *)value;
- (void)addUsers:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeUsers:(NSSet *)values;
```

In the destination view controller, when i do `[self.event add]` , i can't get `addUsersObject`. I thinks its because i didn't `alloc` and `init` Event. but if i do this, i would create a new event object. i need the object from the select row.

Comment: are you importing the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you declare the `event` property in `EventsViewController.h`

You need to declare it as an `Event` class property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Event *event;
```

In order to use the `Event` class you'll need to import the header file into `EventsViewController.h`

```
#import "Event.h"
```

If your code-completion is still not working, you may need to delete the derived data for the project - Close your project, then go to the Organizer, select your project, and click the Delete... button next to Derived Data.  Then reopen the project - after the indexing finishes you should regain your code completion.

Comment: It's so obvious. I declared the event property as a NSManagedObject. Thank you!